# Failure handler issue using Vertx web routes and Minity in a Quarkus application

Tags: vert.x, quarkus, smallrye

I have tried to use Munity  API and Vertx Route together. The complete codes are [here](https://github.com/hantsy/quarkus-sample/tree/master/vertx-routes-munity).

I defined a router rule like this.

```java
 router.put("/posts/:id").consumes("application/json").handler(BodyHandler.create()).handler(handlers::update);
```

And the handler implementation is like this.

```java
    LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "\npath param id: {0}\nrequest body: {1}", new Object[]{id, body});
        var form = fromJson(body, PostForm.class);
        this.posts.findById(UUID.fromString(id))
                .onFailure(PostNotFoundException.class).invoke(ex -> rc.response().setStatusCode(404).end())
                .map(
                        post -> {
                            post.setTitle(form.getTitle());
                            post.setContent(form.getContent());

                            return this.posts.update(UUID.fromString(id), post);
                        }
                )
                .subscribe()
                .with(data -> rc.response().setStatusCode(204).end());
```

In the `findById` method , it throws an `PostNotFoundException`.

```java
    public Uni<Post> findById(UUID id) {
        return this.client
                .preparedQuery("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id=$1")
                .execute(Tuple.of(id))
                .map(RowSet::iterator)
                // .map(it -> it.hasNext() ? rowToPost(it.next()) : null);
                .flatMap(it -> it.hasNext() ? Uni.createFrom().item(rowToPost(it.next())) : Uni.createFrom().failure(PostNotFoundException::new));
    }
```

When running the application, and do update(via HTTP PUT method) on the `/posts/postid` with a none existing post id, it will print a 404 error status as expected, but there is some **pause time** in the period.

In another handler method, it calls `findById` like the following and it works well and responds quickly when it is not found.

```java
        this.posts.findById(UUID.fromString(id))
                .subscribe()
                .with(
                        post -> rc.response().end(toJson(post)),
                        throwable -> rc.fail(404, throwable)
                );
```

Comment: did you find a solution to this? did you post on the quarkus issues on github?

Comment: Not created an issue yet, I guess this is a Munity issue? I hope there are some approaches to avoid this.